# Software Riddle [Part 3!]

Tags: riddle

```
This is another software riddle. It's a game... Enjoy!
```

I run off of a cup of joe
I virtualized the sandbox
And brought construction to the poor
Some exploited me, and rose to wealth

My founder once was loyal
But now he left, a billionare
The company that bought me-
Both small and big-
With a worldwide influence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> Minecraft

I run off of a cup of joe

> Minecraft is written in Java (a language and also another name for coffee)

I virtualized the sandbox

> You play in a virtual sandbox world.

And brought construction to the poor

> The game lets anyone create/construct things in a virtual world.

Some exploited me, and rose to wealth

> You can apparently make money selling Minecraft perks and services.  ([source](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2014/06/07/minecraft-paid-servers/))

My founder once was loyal, But now he left, a billionare

> Markus Persson founded Mojang, the company that created Minecraft.  He stayed for 4 years before selling out to Microsoft for $2.5 billion.

The company that bought me-, Both small and big-, With a worldwide influence

> Microsoft is a huge company with worldwide influence.  "Micro" means small.

Comment: Nice, I didn't expect such a fast answer :)

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 The "small and big" clue immediately said Microsoft to me, so I just figured out who they acquired recently.

Comment: Nice one, the just-published riddle is much harder :)

Answer (score 4):

Quy, I would suggest obscuring the answer more. By saying it's software and a game, you make it obvious.

For instance, say something like this:

> The fruit of the brew of the bean, a multiverse was born. Though all of the gods came to marvel, the creator abandoned it. Twas cheapened by the demons exploiting its denizens and the dominator whose glass fingers gently pull strings. Now, the world is changed. Inside of boxes and pockets, the multiverse is broken and diasporic. Brown, Grey, Silver, Gold, and Blue. The colors run pale as meaning bleeds away.

Keep at it, keep improving, and keep enjoying the artform. See things in abstractions. Microsoft is known for Windows OS, therefore "glassy" and gentle meaning soft. Try and use words that suggest a wildly different answer. Riddle about a goat? Use aquatic terms. Riddling about sunshine? Use math terms. Mix it up and make the community sweat for a day or two coming up with the answer. Finish a riddle, then start over. Change the tone, the language, and anything else you can. Only post second or third drafts, and only post those if they're awesome.

Comment: How can anyone say we don't have experts here